# Is there any tool to display swatch sheet in a document?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, swatches

I'm looking for a tool or strategy (web app, software, Photoshop feature etc.) that will let me display all swatches I have in a '.aco' or '.ase' file in a table and saved as a PDF (preferably) for documentation. When I picture it in my head I'm seeing something like a periodic table, showing the color in a square and adjacent to it showing the RGB for that color. It's basically to share the brand color palette to our dev teams who doesn't have the Adobe suite to look up colors themselves.

Does anyone know of any tool that does what I describe?

Comment: something like the one on dribbble.com ?
link: http://bit.ly/13hGXV5

*Look on the right side of the picture under the droplet small icon, there is a strip of colors in the viewed image.

Comment: Yea, pretty close at least. Though I would prefer to have it displayed statically, to print it or add it to a documentation. So I need a solution that doesn't require hover to see colour codes.

Comment: I think the tool you are looking for is you and your computer, or if you are in the position for it, an intern. You have given what you want some thought and thus likely know best how to make it. Using Photoshop will allow you to upload a theme to Kuler. How many swatches are you talking about?

Comment: @brnnnrsmssn 116... =\ And no, I'm not in a position to assign an intern to it, we don't have any interns here. I feel that I have some more pressing tasks than to commit the time needed to document the swatch sheet. I provided a temporary solution now, involving the cutting out of the swatch sheet from our brand book and getting the colour codes for the swatching using ColorZilla in Firefox. However that only works when you're on a desktop/laptop.

Comment: The intern thing was intended as a joke. Quick google search and I found these: [Palette Parser](http://www.webbiscuit.co.uk/software/palette-parser/) and [Babel Color](http://www.babelcolor.com/#PatchTool). Also tried opening an *.ase file with notepad—the color values seem to be stored in plain text. As a side project you could maybe write a javascript that would extract the color information from the file and dynamically write some HTML and CSS to display exactly what you are wanting. Then a simple print to .pdf would work.

Comment: @brnnnrsmssn thanks for your input, and for the laugh. =)
I tried the Palette Parser (thanks for the tip) but it keeps crashing, something wrong with the app dll file... You know, that side project does sound interesting. unfortunately my knowledge in JS is close to zero, so it would be somewhat of a struggle I assume. I thank you for your input!

Comment: Your struggle to learn JS could make the world a better place... I can see how something like this would be useful for lots of designers. I, as an intern, made swatch pages as you described, fortunately there were only approximately 10 colors that needed doing at a time. Also if you do or ever will do anything relating to web design having an understanding of JS can make you a better designer, even if you do not do the coding.

Comment: @brnnnrsmssn I really like your reasoning. And of course, I have played with the idea to get acquainted with JS, even though it's not mandatory for my area of responsibility it's still good to have an idea of how it works to deliver better design solutions. I'm gonna make this a ToDo project of mine. I have quite a few people around me that are more than well adapt to JS so I could probably get the help I need from them. When there's a functioning prototype I'll post it here.

Comment: @AndroidHustle Also you have, or can have, access to StackOverflow as well as several other StackExchange sites that could provide help. If you make it and it generates a significant amount of interest Adobe could potentially include a similar feature into future versions. Maybe even buy or license your implementation from you if you copyright it. You never know unless you do it and first. Also I think you meant "adept".

Answer (score 3):

For that i use "[ColorSchemer](http://www.colorschemer.com)", i think is the best tool for that, and also, is compatible PC and MAC + iOS App!

> [ColorSchemer Studio 2](http://www.colorschemer.com) is a professional color matching application for
> anyone from hobbyists to advanced professionals.
>
> Work with a dynamic visual color wheel, instantly explore harmony
> relationships and even let ColorSchemer Studio intelligently suggest
> color schemes for you!

## Some Features are:

> **Create and save color palettes**
>
> Select a starting color and ColorSchemer Studio does the rest. Save
> your color schemes to build your own color palette library, ready to
> use for any project.
>
> **Identify color harmonies**
>
> Use the dynamic color wheel to identify color harmonies and matching colors based around any starting color.
> It even spins like a real-life artist color wheel!

Comment: Can ou explain a little bit more? Suppose the link is broken ...

Comment: the link is not broken ! this software allow the possibility to import .aco, .ase and other files and export the colors swatches to pdf, css and more...

Comment: What will be the content of your answer if the link is broken? Can your answer then help someone? Thats the reason why it is better to write with own word a relevant answer ..

Comment: The link is not broken !!!!!!!!! I can click on it without any problem, it may be that you have a problem !

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE, GilbertOOI, and thanks for your contribution! Since we are a community with a Q&A-structured site, we like our good answers to have a bit more that a link to another site -- just in case the link breaks at a later time. Please refer to the about page http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/about and the help center http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help for info about how we like to do things here. And please keep on contributing!

Comment: @GilbertOOl: in Kurt's comment above, "suppose the link is broken" means "pretend that the link has broken" or "what if the link breaks." In that scenario, your answer becomes incomplete and then future visitors will not benefit from your contribution.

Comment: Ok sorry for this ! I thought the link was work because I see and I could click on it! But not ! So, the software named "ColorSchemer" ! Search on the web

Answer (score 0):

5 years later, although I believe the solution has been around for quite a while:

Download and run the following free **Java(Extend)Script** from within **Illustrator**:

https://github.com/johnwun/js4ai/blob/master/renderSwatchLegend.jsx

More detailed explanation: open the .ase in Illustrator. Move the swatches from your .ase palette to the swatches panel. (You might want to remove the default swatches first). Run the script from `file→scripts→other scripts`. It will generate a swatch legend that looks like this:

[image]